# What's the best way to list working for a company that was then acquired by another?

Tags: discussion, questions, jobs

In my career I have two different instances of working for a company which was then acquired by another company. In both cases the acquirer was a larger, known-name company which I'd like to list on my resume.

However at the same time, in one of these cases 80% of my time was spent at the pre-acquisition company, and it would feel wrong to me to claim that I worked for Big Company for the entire 4 year period.

Is there an accepted way to represent this on your CV? I'm nervous that if I attempt to enter something like "Small Company Name / Big Company Name" in the `Company or Employer` field that this might mess with string matching if I chose to hide my resume from either of these employers.

Or should I list these companies as distinct entries in my CV?

How are other people handling this scenario in their own CV?

Comment: If this keeps on happening, maybe you're some kind of sleeper industrial agent working from the inside to prepare for the takeover by the new company?

Comment: I wish. I bet employers would really find that attractive.

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me - one job was at four companies (original, buy out, takeover, takeover).

I list them as four separate companies with an explanation of the circumstances of the change.

Answer (score 3):

- Original Company, LLC. (2001-2003)

  Assistant Programmer, Coffee Maid, Postal Boy.

  Brought out by Second Company, LLC on Jan 25th 2003.
- Second Company, LLC. (2003-2004)

  Programmer, Design Architect.

  Taken over by Third Company, LLC on Feb 25th 2004.
- Third Company, INC. (2004 - 2007)

  Division Lead Programmer, Project Designer, Project Head.

  Taken over by Google on Jul 4th 2007. (Because all company's eventually end at Google.)
- Google (2007 - Present)

  Head Programming, Project Lead for Projects in North East USA area.

Comment: Makes you look like a job hopper.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with you on that one. After all, it's noted that the previous company was taken over by the next.